# Using a fit node over a shadow to include the shadow

Tags: tikz-pgf, shadows, fit

I've used the a double copy shadow (from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159326/5109)) to add multiple rectangles to a node. I would now like to wrap that node and several others with a fit node, but it seems like the fit node does not include the shadows.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,positioning,calc,fit}
\tikzset{multiple/.style = {double copy shadow={shadow xshift=1ex,shadow
         yshift=-1.5ex,draw=black!30},fill=white,draw=black,thick,minimum height = 1cm,minimum
           width=2cm},
         ordinary/.style = {rectangle,draw,thick,minimum height = 1cm,minimum width=2cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [ordinary] at (0,0) (a) {Some};
   \node [multiple,below=3cm of a] (b) {Text};
   \draw[-latex] (a) -- coordinate (ab) (b);
   \draw (ab) -- ++(0.7,-0.5)coordinate[pos=.3](ab1) coordinate[pos=.6](ab2);
   \draw[-latex] (ab1) -- ($(b.north west)!(ab1)!(b.north east)$);
   \draw[-latex] (ab2) -- ($(b.north west)!(ab2)!(b.north east)$);

   \node [fit=(a)(b),draw,rectangle] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results with:

[image: rendered example]

Is it possible to change the code to include them?

Comment: I think the best solution would be to somehow add anchors to the shadow, so that it can be added to the fit list. Alternatively, you could define your `multiple` style to add an empty `label` (for instance `label={[name=\tikzlastnode-shadow,shift={(1cm+2ex,-0.5cm-3ex)}]center:}`, and then you add `b-shadow` in the fit list). I don't see how to easily make it work in the general case.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do what I want. I was also wondering how to make sure a matrix cell includes all the shadows, but I guess that's a matter for a different question.

Comment: By default, shadows aren't even in the current bounding box (unless they happen to be because something else is). This is why a `standalone` image which is cropped will happily exclude shadows. They just aren't there as far as the bounding box is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

If occupancy increase due to shadows is known, it's possible to define a `fit shadow` style with increased `x|y sep` to include shadows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,positioning,calc,fit}
\tikzset{%
multiple/.style = {%
    double copy shadow={%
        shadow xshift=1ex, 
        shadow yshift=-1.5ex, 
        draw=black!30},
    fill=white, 
    draw=black,
    thick,
    minimum height = 1cm,
    minimum width=2cm},
ordinary/.style = {%
    rectangle,
    draw,
    thick,
    minimum height = 1cm,
    minimum width=2cm},
fit shadow/.style = {%
    fit = #1,
    inner xsep=2ex+.3333em,
    inner ysep=3ex+.3333em}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [ordinary] at (0,0) (a) {Some};
   \node [multiple, below=3cm of a] (b) {Text};
   \draw[-latex] (a) -- coordinate (ab) (b);
   \draw (ab) -- ++(0.7,-0.5)coordinate[pos=.3](ab1) coordinate[pos=.6](ab2);
   \draw[-latex] (ab1) -- ($(b.north west)!(ab1)!(b.north east)$);
   \draw[-latex] (ab2) -- ($(b.north west)!(ab2)!(b.north east)$);

   \node [fit shadow=(a)(b), draw, rectangle] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As an alternative, it's also possible to include the desired shadow corner in `fit` list:

```
\node [fit={(a)([shift={(2ex,-3ex)}]b.south east)}, draw, rectangle] {};
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, though I liked the solution with the anchors better because it works automatically even if the shadow turns out to be not at the edge of the fit note.

Comment: @haggai_e: It's another manual solution, but you can decide which particular coordinate include inside `fit` node. I've included an example in my answer.